# Spring does not load properties

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea, properties

Currently I'm learning to work with Spring and I'm already failing at just adding some properties.

For the beginning I tried to keep it simple.
I have a maven project and created a config.properties in the resources folder.

```
test.abc = def
```

Then I created a controller class with the following code:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class Controller {

    @Value("${test.abc}")
    private String abc;

    public Controller() {
        System.out.println(abc);
    }
}
```

My main class looks like that:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BookingdisplayApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Controller();
    }
}
```

Now when I run my code through Intellij or `mvnw.cmd spring-boot:run` I get null in the output. What did I wrong?

Comment: You create Controller with constructor new, it is not managed by Spring. Please, read documentation of Spring Beans.

Answer (score 0):

Is the lifecycle of your controller managed by Spring? You probably need to add annotation @Controller to the class or define bean of this class.

EDIT: 
I think better approach would be to use constructor injection:

Controller.java:

```
public class Controller {

    private String abc;

    public Controller(String abc) {
        this.abc = abc;
        System.out.println(abc);
    }
}
```

BookingdisplayApplication.java:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BookingdisplayApplication {

    // instantiating bean via Spring:
    @Bean
    public Controller controller(@Value("${test.abc}") String testAbc) {
        return new Controller(testAbc);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BookingdisplayApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

You also don't need to use @PropertySource annotation - if you use property file

```
[src-root]/application.properties
```

(in source root), it will be found by Spring automatically.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty new to Spring. I added my main class to the topic. Do you mean that? I don't have more than that

Comment: Nope, you just adds '@Controller' annotation to your Controller class, which ensures that Spring will create a new instance, or you define getter annotated with '@Bean' annotation, see https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java

Comment: I added @Controller at the top of my controller class, but it is still null

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class AppConfig {

    @Value("${test.abc}")
    private String abc;

  //Used in addition of @PropertySource
  @Bean
  public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer   propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
      return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
  }

}
```

Comment: I added the missing part, but it doesn't work as well

Answer (score 0):

Please understand, to resolve ${} in @Values, you must register a static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer in either XML or annotation configuration file.

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

OR,

```
@Autowired
private org.springframework.core.env.Environment env;

//define in your class or method
String abc = env.getProperty("test.abc");
```

Comment: I tried the first thing, it doesn't work. I also tried the second thing, but env returns null

Comment: Annotate your controller class with @Configuration

Comment: I tried that too, with both your suggestions and it's still not working

Comment: Yes, because your controller class isn't instantiated by Spring, you are using 'new' keyword to create object of your controller class. Autowiring would work only if Spring container is taking care of the bean initialization. Both the solutions above would work only if Spring is in role.